# Как сделать time(), но если консоль закроется, то это приостановит работу на C

Tags: c

Допустим, у меня есть программа. Есть код и премиум. Надо, если консоль закроется, то и time(*время*) *приостановит* работу. И если при запуски консоль откроется, то time() *продолжит* свою работу.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
int code = 123;
int your;

printf("Введите код: ")
scanf("%d", your)
if (your == code){
printf("Вы получили премиум на 2 минуты")
time(120) // Вот тут
printf("Ваш премиум истёк!")
}
else
    printf("Ошибка")
}
```

Можно ли сделать такое?

**Может пригодится и мне, и другим :)**

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Начнем с `scanf("%d", &your)`. А так — ну, храните на диске раз в секунду...

Comment: Запишите в файл время, когда премиум должен закончиться и при запуске проверяйте, вышло ли это время. Если нет, то ждите еще столько, сколько надо

Comment: Спасибо вам всем